# Getting File name from the String

Tags: c#, string

Could you help me for finding the file name from the string. Now i have one string of content like "C:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\abc.pdf". But i want only the file name ie. abc.pdf. How it will get by using string functions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx):

```
string full = @"C:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\abc.pdf";
string file = Path.GetFileName(full);
Console.WriteLine(file); // abc.pdf
```

Note that this *assumes* the last part of the name is a file - it doesn't check. So if you gave it "C:\Windows\System32" it would claim a filename of System32, even though that's actually a directory. (Passing in "C:\Windows\System32\" would return an empty string, however.) You can use [`File.Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) to check that a file exists *and is a file rather than a directory* if that would help.

This method also doesn't check that all the other elements in the directory hierarchy exist - so you could pass in "C:\foo\bar\baz.txt" and it would return baz.txt even if foo and bar don't exist.

Comment: @Dilse Naaz: I don't understand your comment, I'm afraid. The code I've shown deals with strings.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Path.GetFileName() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx)

(Edited) sample from the MSDN-page:

```
string fileName = @"C:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\abc.pdf";
string path = @"C:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\";
string path2 = @"C:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx";

string result;

result = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    fileName, result);

result = Path.GetFileName(path);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    path, result);

result = Path.GetFileName(path2);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    path2, result);
```

This code produces output similar to the following:

```
GetFileName('C:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\abc.pdf') returns 'abc.pdf'
GetFileName('C:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\') returns ''
GetFileName('C:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx') returns 'xxxx'
```

Answer (score 2):

`Sytem.IO.FileInfo` is also quite cool:
In your case you can do

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("C:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\abc.pdf");
string name = fi.Name; // it gives you abc.pdf
```

Then you can have several other pieces of information:
does the file really exist? `fi.Exists` gives you the answer
what's its extension? see `fi.Extension`
what's the name of its directory? see `fi.Directory`
etc.

Have a look at [all the members of FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo_members(v=VS.80).aspx) you may find something interesting for your needs

Answer (score 0):

Use the methods of [System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx), especially
[Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

System.IO.Path.GetFilename(yourFilename) 
will return the name of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(string path)`:

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("C:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\abc.pdf")
```

And you would get back `abc`