# what is the best way to split a string

Tags: c#, string

I have file name which look like

> Directory\name-secondName-blabla.txt

If I using string .split my code need to know the separator I am using,
But if in some day I will replace the separator my code will break

**Is the any build in way to split to get the following result?**

```
Directory
name
secondNmae
blabla
txt
```

Thanks

**Edit** My question is more general than just split file name, is splitting string in general

Comment: Couldn't you just use a function that calls split and whose one of its arguments is the separator?

Comment: Man, try to search a little SO:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742688/getting-file-name-from-the-string
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105593/get-file-name-from-uri-string-in-c
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401304/c-how-do-i-extract-each-folder-name-from-a-path
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736462/c-getting-the-folder-name-from-a-path

Comment: I think everyone seems to have not read this question properly!

Comment: It seems that no one read my Edit also

Comment: "[when] I will replace the separator my code will break" - Yes, it ususally does. You'll have to give a more detailed scenario.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to split a *filename* is to use `System.IO.Path`

You're not clear about what to do with  `directory1\directory2\` ,
but in general you should use this static class to find the *path*, *name* and *suffix* parts.

After that you will need `String.Split()` to handle the `-` separators, you'll just have to make the separator(s) a config setting.

Comment: Easy to get the filename, but not what the OP was asking.

Comment: @Tim B: That is why filename was in italics

Comment: @Henk Yes I understood, but your answer was pretty basic before you edited it and wasn't really helpful to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can make an array with seperators:

```
string value = "Directory\name-secondName-blabla.txt";
char[] delimiters = new char[] { '\\', '-', '.' };
string[] parts = value.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var filepath = @"Directory\name-secondName-blabla.txt";
var tokens = filepath.Split(new[]{'\\', '-'});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about your separator token changing in the future, set it as a constant in a settings file so you only have to change it in one place. Or, if you think it is going to change regularly, put it in a config file so you don't have to release new builds every time.

Answer (score 0):

As Henk suggested above, use `System.IO.Path` and its static methods like `GetFileNameWithoutExtenstion`, `GetDirectoryName`, etc. Have a look at this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx