# How to get file name from this string

Tags: c#, string

How can I get fileName from this string:

```
"C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Lighthouse.jpg"
```

For example, my result must be: `"Lighthouse.jpg"`.

Comment: Is Google down today or something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting File name from the String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742688/getting-file-name-from-the-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
stirng filePath = @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Lighthouse.jpg";

string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);
```

Or

```
string fileName = filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf("\\")+1);
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use `Path.GetFileName` [(msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
using System.IO;
// ...
var filePath = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Lighthouse.jpg";
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use Path.GetFileName.

```
        var filePath = @"E:\raviiii\fibo.txt";
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        Console.WriteLine(fileName);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code sample:

```
string fileName = @"C:\mydir\myfile.ext";
string path = @"C:\mydir\";
string result;

result = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    fileName, result);
```